# Force to use specific pdf viewer in android

Tags: android, pdf, open-source, viewer

I want user to use my pdf viewer instead of using OS suggested list of viwer(s). Is there is any chance i can achieve this functionality.
I have secure folder where there are pdf files. What ia m looking for is when user opens that folder at that time only my pdf viewer should be used.

Comment: You can't.  Android enforces this via the intent filter registrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the FSM you can't. There is no reason for you to take this freedom from end user.

If you need such a requirement, create a viewer application from scratch and asociate it to your own, newly created file extension.